# Одноразовое добавление данных в CodeFirst БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, codefirst

Создаю приложение с CodeFirst БД на Entity Framework.

Необходимо чтобы при создании БД одноразово были добавлены стандартные данные. 
Попробовал при загрузке окна добавлять в БД данные, но при каждой загрузке эти данные добавлялись снова.

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: [Seed Data in EF 6 Code-First](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx), [Присвоение начальных значений данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)

Answer (score 0):

Всё это описано в следующей статье:
https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level2/2_10.php

Comment: ответ - ссылка?

Answer (score 0):

Создаем класс, который наследует один из следующих классов инициализаторов:

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists: инициализатор, используемый по умолчанию. Он не удаляет автоматчески базу данных и данные, а в случае изменения структуры моделей и контекста данных выбрасывает исключение.
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges: данный инициализатор проверяет на соответствие моделям определения таблиц в базе данных. И если модели не соответствуют определению таблиц, то база данные пересоздается
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways: этот инициализатор будет всегда пересоздавать базу данных.

В полученном классе нам нужно переопределить метод Seed. Внутри него мы можем проинициализировать таблицы нашей базы данных через DbSet'ы:

```
class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<КонтекстВашейБазыДанных>
{
    protected override void Seed(КонтекстВашейБазыДанных context)
    {
        // Обращаемся к DbSet'ам параметра context и заполняем их данными.
    }
}
```

Мы получили готовый класс, инициализирующий таблицы нашей базы данных. Теперь его нужно задать нашему классу-контексту:

```
public КонтекстВашейБазыДанных : DbContext
{
    static КонтекстВашейБазыДанных()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<КонтекстВашейБазыДанных>(new MyInitializer());
    }
}
```

Я создал статический конструктор, где задаю инициализатор.
Подробнее можете прочитать [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.9.php).